# Filtering Overpass-API by country

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, overpass-api, search

Does anyone know how to perform a overpass-api request like this?

"Show me all banks in Germany"?

I could just show all 'amenity = bank' in a specific bounding-box. But Germany (or most of all countries) doesn't fit very well in such a bbox.

Is there any way to do this? Have you an example? Server performance or runtime is secondary since we could host a own server or something like that :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using Overpass turbo, the syntax is:

```
area["name"="Nordrhein-Westfalen"]->.boundaryarea;
(
nwr(area.boundaryarea)[amenity=bank];
);
out meta;
```

`nwr` is a short for `node`-`way`-`relation`

Comment: It helped me to write ">;" after the closing round bracket ");" and before "out". Otherwise no nodes with coordinates in the map were displayed.

Comment: @qräbnö you are right, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The Quick OSM plugin for QGIS generates the following working Overpass query:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="200"> 
 <id-query {{nominatimArea:Austria}} into="area"/> 
 <union>
      <query type="node">
           <has-kv k="amenity" v="bank"/> 
           <area-query from="area"/>
      </query>
      <query type="way">
           <has-kv k="amenity" v="bank"/> 
           <area-query from="area"/>
      </query>
      <query type="relation">
           <has-kv k="amenity" v="bank"/> 
           <area-query from="area"/>
      </query>
 </union>
 <union>
      <item />
      <recurse type="down"/>
 </union>
 <print mode="body" />
</osm-script>
```

for details see [Overpass turbo/Extended Overpass Queries](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Queries)